# Multiple Monitors Remote Desktop VM in Cloud

Tags: multiple-monitors

Currently, I am using 3 monitors on my desktop PC as I run a software with many windows and I save and restore the layouts(work space) of these widows.

I am planning to move to the could and was wondering how this would work in the cloud world.  What I am not quite clear about 
1. Can I configure the cloud VM to have 3 monitors just like the way I have it
2. Or am I thinking about this wrong, I just expand the RDP window across my monitors and then just work with it.

Please provide any insights as to how is it generally done in a multiple monitor setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDP support multiple monitors, you can check that option in the client settings.

The number of monitors depend on the client, not the server.

If the remote OS support it, it will work.

Make sure your apps working well on remote session by connect to your current pc from a different one.

See Server OS restrictions here: https://support.steadfast.net/Knowledgebase/Article/View/107/0/using-multiple-monitors-with-windows-remote-desktop

> When connecting to Windows 7 computers, only computers that are running Windows 7 Enterprise or Ultimate can be connected to in multi-monitor mode. When connecting to Windows 8.1, only computers that are running Windows 8.1 Professional or Enterprise can be connected to in multi-monitor mode.